# Value matching from a list of v

Tags: php, html, css

How can I make a simple script to find the same values from a list and highlight them? ! 
To make it clear, I have parameters (values with checkboxes) and when I click one or more checkboxes, I would want the script to find the same values and highlight (or color the cell) from a list of values. Can someone give me an idea how to do this please or if you know a similar script that would  be helpful too. I know basic html/css/php/mysql.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
body  {
 font: 100% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 background: #666666;
 margin: 0; /* it's good practice to zero the margin and padding of the body element to account for differing browser defaults */
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center; /* this centers the container in IE 5* browsers. The text is then set to the left aligned default in the #container selector */
 color: #000000;
}
.twoColLiqLt #container { 
 width: 80%;  /* this will create a container 80% of the browser width */
 background: #FFFFFF;
 margin: 0 auto; /* the auto margins (in conjunction with a width) center the page */
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 text-align: left; /* this overrides the text-align: center on the body element. */
} 

/* Tips for sidebar1:
1. since we are working in percentages, it's best not to use padding on the sidebar. It will be added to the width for standards compliant browsers creating an unknown actual width. 
2. Space between the side of the div and the elements within it can be created by placing a left and right margin on those elements as seen in the ".twoColLiqLt #sidebar1 p" rule.
3. Since Explorer calculates widths after the parent element is rendered, you may occasionally run into unexplained bugs with percentage-based columns. If you need more predictable results, you may choose to change to pixel sized columns.
*/
.twoColLiqLt #sidebar1 {
 float: left; 
 width: 24%; /* since this element is floated, a width must be given */
 background: #EBEBEB; /* the background color will be displayed for the length of the content in the column, but no further */
 padding: 15px 0; /* top and bottom padding create visual space within this div  */
}
.twoColLiqLt #sidebar1 h3, .twoColLiqLt #sidebar1 p {
 margin-left: 10px; /* the left and right margin should be given to every element that will be placed in the side columns */
 margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Tips for mainContent:
1. the space between the mainContent and sidebar1 is created with the left margin on the mainContent div.  No matter how much content the sidebar1 div contains, the column space will remain. You can remove this left margin if you want the #mainContent div's text to fill the #sidebar1 space when the content in #sidebar1 ends.
2. to avoid float drop at a supported minimum 800 x 600 resolution, elements within the mainContent div should be 430px or smaller (this includes images).
3. in the Internet Explorer Conditional Comment below, the zoom property is used to give the mainContent "hasLayout." This avoids several IE-specific bugs.
*/
.twoColLiqLt #mainContent { 
 margin: 0 20px 0 26%; /* the right margin can be given in percentages or pixels. It creates the space down the right side of the page. */
} 

/* Miscellaneous classes for reuse */
.fltrt { /* this class can be used to float an element right in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
 float: right;
 margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { /* this class can be used to float an element left in your page */
 float: left;
 margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { /* this class should be placed on a div or break element and should be the final element before the close of a container that should fully contain a float */
 clear:both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
--> 
</style><!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css"> 
/* place css fixes for all versions of IE in this conditional comment */
.twoColLiqLt #sidebar1 { padding-top: 30px; }
.twoColLiqLt #mainContent { zoom: 1; padding-top: 15px; }
/* the above proprietary zoom property gives IE the hasLayout it needs to avoid several bugs */
</style>
<![endif]--></head>

<body class="twoColLiqLt">

<div id="container">
  <div id="sidebar1">
    <h3>Parameters:</h3>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="x" id="x" />
        x</label>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="y" id="y" />
      y</label>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="z" id="z" />
      z</label>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q" id="q" />
      q</label>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="xy" id="xy" />
      xy</label>
    </form>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <!-- end #sidebar1 --></div>
  <div id="mainContent">
    <h1>Values:</h1>
    <table width="611" height="129" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>q</td>
        <td>q</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>q</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>q</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>q</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>xy</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>xy</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>z</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
 
    <!-- end #mainContent --></div>
 <!-- This clearing element should immediately follow the #mainContent div in order to force the #container div to contain all child floats --><br class="clearfloat" />
<!-- end #container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can You provide the code You are working on ?

Comment: Can You please edit Your question and put the code there ?

Comment: Now I managed to do it, i guess.

Comment: So to achieve this I think  You should familiarize Yourself with `jQuery`

Comment: Thanks @Michal, but I don't know anything about jQuery and wouldn't know where to start. There might be an alternative to jquery?

Comment: yes, this is how I'd want it. but there are two issues here; when I do unclick, it still keeps highlighting, and it doesn't let more than two parameters highlighted at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what You are looking for. please note added `highlight` class to CSS and at the bottom `jQuery` library and `<script>` section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body  {
    font: 100% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #666666;
    margin: 0; /* it's good practice to zero the margin and padding of the body element to account for differing browser defaults */
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center; /* this centers the container in IE 5* browsers. The text is then set to the left aligned default in the #container selector */
    color: #000000;
}
.twoColLiqLt #container {
    width: 80%;  /* this will create a container 80% of the browser width */
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto; /* the auto margins (in conjunction with a width) center the page */
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: left; /* this overrides the text-align: center on the body element. */
}

/* Tips for sidebar1:
1. since we are working in percentages, it's best not to use padding on the sidebar. It will be added to the width for standards compliant browsers creating an unknown actual width.
2. Space between the side of the div and the elements within it can be created by placing a left and right margin on those elements as seen in the ".twoColLiqLt #sidebar1 p" rule.
3. Since Explorer calculates widths after the parent element is rendered, you may occasionally run into unexplained bugs with percentage-based columns. If you need more predictable results, you may choose to change to pixel sized columns.
*/
.twoColLiqLt #sidebar1 {
    float: left;
    width: 24%; /* since this element is floated, a width must be given */
    background: #EBEBEB; /* the background color will be displayed for the length of the content in the column, but no further */
    padding: 15px 0; /* top and bottom padding create visual space within this div  */
}
.twoColLiqLt #sidebar1 h3, .twoColLiqLt #sidebar1 p {
    margin-left: 10px; /* the left and right margin should be given to every element that will be placed in the side columns */
    margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Tips for mainContent:
1. the space between the mainContent and sidebar1 is created with the left margin on the mainContent div.  No matter how much content the sidebar1 div contains, the column space will remain. You can remove this left margin if you want the #mainContent div's text to fill the #sidebar1 space when the content in #sidebar1 ends.
2. to avoid float drop at a supported minimum 800 x 600 resolution, elements within the mainContent div should be 430px or smaller (this includes images).
3. in the Internet Explorer Conditional Comment below, the zoom property is used to give the mainContent "hasLayout." This avoids several IE-specific bugs.
*/
.twoColLiqLt #mainContent {
    margin: 0 20px 0 26%; /* the right margin can be given in percentages or pixels. It creates the space down the right side of the page. */
}

/* Miscellaneous classes for reuse */
.fltrt { /* this class can be used to float an element right in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
    float: right;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { /* this class can be used to float an element left in your page */
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { /* this class should be placed on a div or break element and should be the final element before the close of a container that should fully contain a float */
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
.highlight {background:#f00;}
-->
</style><!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
/* place css fixes for all versions of IE in this conditional comment */
.twoColLiqLt #sidebar1 { padding-top: 30px; }
.twoColLiqLt #mainContent { zoom: 1; padding-top: 15px; }
/* the above proprietary zoom property gives IE the hasLayout it needs to avoid several bugs */
</style>
<![endif]--></head>

<body class="twoColLiqLt">

<div id="container">
  <div id="sidebar1">
    <h3>Parameters:</h3>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="x" id="x" />
        x</label>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="y" id="y" />
      y</label>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="z" id="z" />
      z</label>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q" id="q" />
      q</label>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="xy" id="xy" />
      xy</label>
    </form>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <!-- end #sidebar1 --></div>
  <div id="mainContent">
    <h1>Values:</h1>
    <table width="611" height="129" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>q</td>
        <td>q</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>q</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>q</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>q</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>xy</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>xy</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>z</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <!-- end #mainContent --></div>
    <!-- This clearing element should immediately follow the #mainContent div in order to force the #container div to contain all child floats --><br class="clearfloat" />
<!-- end #container --></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#form1 input[type="checkbox"]').on('click',function(e) {
        var val = $(this).attr('name');
        $('#mainContent table td').removeClass('highlight');
        $('#mainContent table td').each(function( index ) {

            if ( $( this ).text() == val ) {
                $( this ).addClass('highlight');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, this is how I'd want it. but there are two issues here; when I do unclick, it still keeps highlighting, and it doesn't let more than two parameters highlighted at the same time.

Comment: Yes, it's not a complete solution. But I just wanted to show You how this can be done via `jQuery`. Of course You can do the same using php but it will be more complicated. Try to play around with this and change it to Your needs.